# Backbone.View cannot call a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am trying to call a function but I get an error stating function undefined.

```
window.PackageView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: "div",

    className: "package-template",

    events:{

      "click #display-name"       :    "getNodeId",         
    },

    initialize: function() { 
        _.bindAll(this,'render', 'getNodeId', 'getAction');                      
        this.template = _.template($('#package-template').html());
        $(this.el).html(this.template); //Load the compiled HTML into the Backbone "el"
        nodeInstance.bind('reset', this.render, this);
    },

    render: function() {
       //.. no need to worry about this.
    },


    getNodeId: function(){
        objectJSON = jAccess.getJSON(); // I get the JSON successfully
        nodeIdArray = []
        _.each(objectJSON, function(action){
            _.each(action.Nodes, function(action){
                nodeIdArray.push(action.Id);
                  this.getAction(); // Here is the problem. I get an error
            });    
        });    
    },

    getAction: function(){

       actionsArray = [];
       objectJSON = jAccess.getJSON();
       _.each(objectJSON, function(action){
           _.each(action.Nodes, function(action){
               if(action.Id == 5) {       

               _.each(action.Actions, function(action){
                   actionsArray.push(action.Name);
               });
            }
           });
       });
       console.log(actionsArray);
    }


});
```

I don't know where I am going wrong here. Help me out.

I get an error saying 'undefined' is not a function evaluating ('this.getAction()')

Comment: This is probably a scope issue.  What is the value of the root object console.log(this) at the start of getNodeId() and on the line before the this.getAction()  If they don't match then it is definitely a scoping issue.

Comment: I don't know. I will have to check.

Comment: It says DOMWindow before `this.getAction()`

Comment: And before objectJSON = jAccess.getJSON();?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a simple fix, you should be able to do:

```
getNodeId: function(){
    var self = this;
    objectJSON = jAccess.getJSON();
    nodeIdArray = []
    _.each(objectJSON, function(action){
        _.each(action.Nodes, function(action){
            nodeIdArray.push(action.Id);
              self.getAction();
        });    
    });    
},
```

I think there might be a more elegant solution using underscores bind function, I'll have a check.

**EDIT**
The more elegant solution is only usable when using the each method on a collection from a RESTful resource, so does not apply in this case.  For example if you have a collection of messages, you could do the following to keep context.

```
  addAllMessages: function(messages) {
        messages.each(this.addMessage, this);
    },
```

Comment: @Eric: You REALLY need to read the backbone doc - have it open all the time when coding :) - it addresses this issue here: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-this.